# Move image from left to right then rotate animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm making an example that moving an image from left to right then rotate it self.
I've tried using AnimationSet but the image rotation isn't correct. It moves in a cycle not it self.
How to fix this problem?

What I want
[image]
MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    set.setFillAfter(true);
    img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBanner);
    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
    rotation.setStartOffset(2000);
    rotation.setDuration(2000);
    TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 0);
    moveLefttoRight.setStartOffset(1000);
    moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1000);
    set.addAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
    set.addAnimation(rotation);
    img_animation.startAnimation(set);
}
```

Rotation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="90" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/banner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestion is helpful with me

Comment: Did you try applying each animation separately instead of creating an animation set?

Comment: @neo yes, I've try rotation inside onAnimationEnd of moveLefttoRight. But without setFillAfter(true), the image jump in beginning position and rotate it self. So I switch to AnimationSet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

So it will rotate relative to itself.
Hope this helps.

Edit:

```
image.clearAnimation();
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(30, 360, image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setRepeatCount(0);
anim.setDuration(10000);
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

I tested this one in demo application. Its working great. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: thanks for fast answer but It still rotate in cycle. It rotate around red point on picture above.

Comment: Did you try putting `moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);` ? @Dolphin

Comment: Ok.. refer this: http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=rotating-image-to-itself .. Might help. Just seen

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I've tried your fix at rotation but It still rotate in cycle. I've found a trick that work for me and post It soon. 
But thanks for you enthusiasm so much :D

Comment: Fix your answer a bit then it worked. 
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(30, 360, image.getX() + image.getWidth()/2, image.getY() + image.getHeight()/2)

Comment: Ok... Glad it helped you a bit. I was on leave. Came back today only. :)