# How to code an animation for refresh icon

Tags: android, user-interface, refresh

Issue at hand:

I am currently trying to code an animation function for the refresh icon and so far, through research I have only managed to source this code snippet out:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView iv= (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.spin_refresh, null);
    Animation rotation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DownloadService.this,R.anim.accelerate_decelerate_interpolator);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    iv.startAnimation(rotation);
    refreshItem.setActionView(iv);
    //TODO trigger loading
```

I couldn't actually fully comprehend the codings, are there any simpler way of animation coding or what's the general meaning of the code itself. I have already created a separate animation.xml within the animation folder in res folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to rotate the image to self like [second animation in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345041/move-image-from-left-to-right-then-rotate-animation)

You can use this:

```
image.clearAnimation();
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(30, 360, image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setRepeatCount(0);
anim.setDuration(10000);
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So this is an alternative to the code snippet that I have just given?? Furthermore, I would like to ask; How do the code get the value for  image.getWidth()/2 & image.getHeight()/2?? And in this code itself, i understand that the duration of the animation will only be 10 secs, what happens when the refresh function is not completed within 10s and the timer duration is up?sorry, i am just trying to understand and learn

Comment: you can increase the time as per your liking, and repeat the animation if it takes more time. @ErnestLee.  image.getWidth()/2 & image.getHeight()/2 will be taken from image on run time based on image's width and height. Yes, its an alternate, and easy to understand :)

Comment: sorry with the late reply, I have implemented your method and I am fixing up some syntax error, will inform you on the outcome when I have build the project!!Thanks for your suggestion though!!

Comment: I have implemented the code above and run, there are no errors, however, I am unable to select the refresh icon to let it run.

Comment: Select? what do you mean?

Comment: sorry, it isn't select but at this point in time, i am unable to input the function where the user can click on the refresh button, the refresh button image is there.

Comment: refreshImg.setOnclickListener? @ErnestLee