# Activity closed in middle of work and redirect it to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, forceclose

I am created app for loan survey. In each survey 80 to 90 questions have been displayed. the questions is displayed one by one when he press next button. the views r created programatically and after submitting each question i have removed that views and create another views.

It works fine, but my problem is, 
when i am in 30 to 40 th question suddenly my activity closes and redirect to previous activity. Even it is not executing onPause method also. I dont know what is the problem. There is no app crash also. i don't no whether it caused due to memory error or any other. Please anyone suggest me how to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25718765/1777090)?

Comment: not like that... check above image and it should be rotate as clockwise how the globe will be rotated in 3d. MysticMagic say how to rotate in 3d. thanks in advance

Comment: Using your code, it moves leaving its place. Do you want to animate image in the same place? or want its position to change in circular motion?

Comment: yes. animate image in same place in a circular motion.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/04/21/create-rotate-3d-animation-listview-imageview-android/) along with my post

Answer (score 0):

Here is how close I could reach using combination of my answer of [rotation of image around itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25718840/1777090) and [this post of moving image in a circular path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285942/1777090)

```
//i is my ImageView here
// method to rotate globe
private void applyRotation(float start, float end) {

    //first animation for circular path
    final Animation rotation = new MyAnimation(i, 2000);
    rotation.setDuration(10000);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(0);

    //rotation of iamge
    final Animation rotation2 = new RotateAnimation(30, 360, i.getWidth()/2, i.getHeight()/2);
    rotation2.setFillAfter(true);
    rotation2.setRepeatCount(0);
    rotation2.setDuration(10000);
    rotation2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    //combine in a Set
    AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);

    s.addAnimation(rotation);
    s.addAnimation(rotation2);
    i.startAnimation(s);
}
```

MyAnimation.java

```
package com.example.tempp;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class MyAnimation extends Animation {

    private View view;
    private float cx, cy;           // center x,y position of circular path
    private float prevX, prevY;     // previous x,y position of image during animation
    private float r;                // radius of circle


    /**
     * @param view - View that will be animated
     * @param r - radius of circular path
     */
    public MyAnimation(View view, float r){
        this.view = view;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        // calculate position of image center
        int cxImage = width / 2;
        int cyImage = height / 2;
        cx = view.getLeft() + cxImage;
        cy = view.getTop() + cyImage;

        // set previous position to center
        prevX = cx;
        prevY = cy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        if(interpolatedTime == 0){
            // I ran into some issue where interpolated would be
            return;
        }

        float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 360f + 90) % 360;
        float angleRad = (float) Math.toRadians(angleDeg);

        // r = radius, cx and cy = center point, a = angle (radians)
        float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad));
        float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad));


        float dx = prevX - x;
        float dy = prevY - y;

        prevX = x;
        prevY = y;

        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.